# How to change the column name in SQL using Laravel?

Tags: php, database, laravel-5

I have been following the https://laracasts.com series on Laravel-5 fundamentals, I am little new to all this , MySQL and frameworks..

I used 'php artisan tinker' command to change the attributes for my column.
But I made a typo and typed 'event_desciption' instead of 'event_description'
Now whenever I try to save it using $events->save(); It gives an Error.

The Columns name I gave :

```
                        $table->increments('id');
                        $table->string('event_name');
                        $table->integer('cost');
                        $table->text('event_description');
                        $table->text('terms_and_condition');
                        $table->string('organized_by');
                        $table->timestamps();
                        $table->timestamp('published_at');
```

the typo I made while creating an events object..
    $events;

```
 $events;
=> App\event {#627
     event_name: "My first evenr name",
     cost: 20,
 >event_desciption: " the event description",
 terms_and_condition: " our terms and condition",
 organized_by: "organized by us",
 published_at: Carbon\Carbon {#634
   +"date": "2016-06-07 20:17:44.000000",
   +"timezone_type": 3,
   +"timezone": "UTC",
 },
 updated_at: "2016-06-07 20:19:54",
 created_at: "2016-06-07 20:19:54,
```

The error it gives :

> > > $events->save();
> > >       Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'event_desciption' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `events` (`event_name`, `cost`, `event_desciption`, `terms_and_condition`, `organized_by`, `published_at`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (My first evenr name, 20,  the event description,  our terms and condition, organized by us, 2016-06-07 20:17:44, 2016-06-07 20:19:54, 2016-06-07 20:19:54))'

**How can one Change the column name without without creating an another object to do the same thing?**

Thank You :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To rename a column, you may use the renameColumn method on the Schema
>   builder. Before renaming a column, be sure to add the doctrine/dbal
>   dependency to your composer.json file.
>
> ```
> Schema::table('users', function($table)
> {
>     $table->renameColumn('from', 'to');
> });
> ```

This was a quote from the following page:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema#renaming-columns

So, in your case, you are going to change that line of code to read:

```
$table->renameColumn('event_desciption', 'event_description');
```

EDIT:

You may have put the wrong name in your object if your table schema is correct. Change the property of your `$events` object entitled `event_desciption` to `event_description`.

One way you can accomplish this is by deleting and rebuilding the object again in `php artisan tinker`:

```
$events->delete();
```

Comment: I believe OP has the correct column name in the table schema, but assigned the wrong one to the object.

Comment: Thank You for your time in understanding my problem and answering it@Kenny,  but yes I have assigned the correct column name in the schema, but whilst giving them values I typed the wrong column name ( to the 'events' Object as @Birdman pointed out ) how do I change that without making another object and redoing all the things again.

Comment: @SanyamPhirani I recommend deleting the object with the code above and starting over.